# Radio Buttons, Multiple Dialogs, Jquery

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to make my 3 radio buttons, each pop up with a different dialog box using jquery. (http://www.regrettablehookups.com/sandbox/contact.php)

This is what I have in the header:

```
//Radio Button
$("#radioset").buttonset();
//Button
$("#dialog_button").button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-newwin'
    }
});

// Dialog           
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {
        "Okay": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});


// Dialog Link
$('#dialog_button').click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
});
```

And the code in my body:

```
 <div id="radioset">
    <input type="radio" id="kevin" name="radio" /><label for="kevin">Kevin</label>
    <input type="radio" id="natalie" name="radio" /><label for="natalie">Natalie</label>
    <input type="radio" id="kaitlyn" name="radio" /><label for="kaitlyn">Kaitlyn</label>
 </div>
```

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: if you want the code to look neater, highlight the code part and the press the "code" icon to make it all pretty. I had the same problem.
Also you can edit this post to what i just said by going to the bottom of the post next to the tag it says edit in a fading color.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog1").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Kevin: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Natalie: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog3").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Kaitlyn: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        $("#radioset").buttonset();
        $('#radioset input:radio').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            switch (value) {
                case 'kevin':
                    fireKevin();
                    break;
                case 'natalie':
                    fireNatalie();
                    break;
                case 'kaitlyn':
                    fireKaitlyn();
                    break;
            }
        });
    });

    function fireKevin() {
        $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
    }
    function fireNatalie() {
        $('#dialog2').dialog('open');
    }
    function fireKaitlyn() {
        $('#dialog3').dialog('open');
    }
</script>

<div id="radioset">
    <input type="radio" id="kevin" name="radio" value="kevin" /><label for="kevin">Kevin</label>
    <input type="radio" id="natalie" name="radio" value="natalie" /><label for="natalie">Natalie</label>
    <input type="radio" id="kaitlyn" name="radio" value="kaitlyn" /><label for="kaitlyn">Kaitlyn</label>
</div>

<div id="dialog1">Dialog 1</div>
<div id="dialog2">Dialog 2</div>
<div id="dialog3">Dialog 3</div>
```

By the way, you could just share one dialog window for all three subjects, but depending on your needs, that could easily get really ugly **quick** (say, you need different buttons for each subject, or the inner html needs to change accordingly, etc.).